# How to implement a blog web part through provider hosted App

Tags: office-365, provider-hosted-app

Having an Office 365 subscription.

Have a team site where we need to add functionality of a blog web part but not exactly through OOB server side web part. Rather want to create functionality of a Blog web part but with the implementation of Provider hosted apps.

Please write steps how to do this?

Hope I am able to explain my requirement correctly.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you want to redevelop the wheel?

remember that there should be a blog site template in sp13, you can take it for a try.
http://blog.fpweb.net/understanding-sharepoint-2013-blog-site-templates/#.VKE94f88Lc

Comment: Your answer is different than the question. In a team site we can create blog web part, site template is not required.